# GMap.NET + C# + postgreSQL without Internet connection

Tags: c#, postgresql, gmap.net

I have a desktop app in C# using GMap.NET and it's great, but my app must work without Internet. I thought, I needed kinda PostgreSQLProvider for GMap.NET.

So I downloaded an .osm file for Russian Federation, created a postgresql database with postGIS extention and then executed query, which was generated with [osm2po](http://anitagraser.com/2011/12/15/an-osm2po-quickstart/) (it's huge: 1,2 Gb)

Now I have a databese, which can be visualized with [QGis](http://anitagraser.com/2011/12/18/osm2po-part-2-pgrouting-on-osm-the-easy-way/). I want to visualize this database map in my C# application to handle user mouse button clicks and draw some objects on map.

How can I do that? Maybe I should use another framework? All I need from map is get placemarks in mouse button click handler function and draw objects on map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefetch the maps you want with the demo version of GMAP.NET. Then grab the database generated by the prefetch and use it in your application. its located in

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\GMap.NET\TileDBv5\en\Data.gmdb

the Database is in SQLite but I figure you can convert it to any DBMS you want.

Comment: Thanx for answering.
but I think that the cached information that is used to display and only recently ...

Answer (score 0):

I found, where the problem in. osm2po generate for me vector map, but GMap visualize only raster. The solution is to use another framework, such as SharpMap, that can work with vector maps from database.
Of course, I can write my own PgSQLProvider for GMap, but I have only a month and still many other works.